# OptaPlanner: Constraint matches do not update after problemfact changed

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

I have a UI that lets the user make changes to the problem facts before and after the solving process, i.e. I am doing repeated planning. However, the constraint matches do not get updated when I apply those changes to the score director.

My problem fact changes look something like this:

```
solutionBusiness.doProblemFactChange(scoreDirector -> {
    Patient p = patientAdmissionSchedule.getPatientList().get(0);
    scoreDirector.beforeProblemFactChanged(p);
    p.setPreferredRoomCapacity(2);
    scoreDirector.afterProblemFactChanged(p);
});
```

In this case, the scoreDirector would still show me constraint matches with the old preferredRoomCapacity.

The constraint matches only get updated once I start the solving process again. Is there any way to trigger an update of the constraint matches other than starting the solving process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the working solution, so:

```
Patient p = ((MySchedule) scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution()).getPatientList().get(0);
```

That's a different instance than your original one, see docs chapter "planning clone" etc.